# Usinq Linq to get rows based on comma-separated value

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

I have comma-separated data in my column called `col1`, and I have an array of strings

```
IEnumerable<string> year = {"1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000"}
```

I have tried the following

```
searchfrom = searchfrom.Where(x => years.Contains(x.col1.Replace(',', ' '))).ToList();
```

and

```
searchfrom = searchfrom.Where(x => years.Contains(x.col1)).ToList();
```

I want that row which is match any "year" into "col1"

Comment: Linq-to-_What_? What is `searchfrom`? What is `years`? Also, the array is not an array, that won't compile.

Comment: "searchfrom" is my Result / List of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To optimize such queries, you should first convert your `years` collection into a hash set.

```
var years = new HashSet<string>(new [] { "1990", "1991", ... });
```

In your `Where` clause, you need to split the contents of each of your records, `x`, for which you can use `x.Split(',')`. Then, you need to check whether any of these subparts are contained within the `years` collection.

```
var result = searchfrom.Where(x => 
    x.Split(',').Any(years.Contains)
).ToList();
```